# Building ADS1299 driver for Portenta H7 using Arduino SPI library

Tags: arduino, spi, mbed

ADS1299 Dev Board from TI I try to connect to an Arduino Portenta H7. [Library for Portenta H7 with ADS1299](https://github.com/ashfaquekhan/PortentaADS). [Raspberry Pi Pico library for ADS1299](https://github.com/indrayudd/PicoADS1299/tree/main) I am using as reference. Driver for Raspberry Pi Pico was made using [this library](https://github.com/chipaudette/OpenBCI/blob/master/Arduino/Libraries/ADS1299/ADS1299.cpp).

Comment: Well, it uses some PicoSPI.h so suppose it's something existing only for pico. SPI instance is pretty much hardcoded to be exactly what picoSPI provides, so at most you can try replace that with SPI and hope it's at least a bit compatible

Comment: Yeah but the Pico lib for ads1299 was written using the OpenBCI ADS1299 driver for arduino itself https://github.com/chipaudette/OpenBCI/blob/master/Arduino/Libraries/ADS1299/ADS1299.cpp

Comment: You didn't describe what is not working and what exactly is the problem you are facing and exactly what you need help. BTW, to only calling SPI.beginTransaction() only once in the init, you are going to hold up the SPI bus for as long as the library is running, this might work for the chip you are using, but if there is more than one SPI device on the bus, the other chip won't be able to communicate via SPI.

Comment: SPI transactional API allows user to setup configuration for each transaction and release the SPI bus by calling SPI.endTransaction(). SPI Transactional APIs has been introduced in 2014, and the Arduino ADS1299 driver you were referring to is using deprecated SPI API.

Comment: @hcheung Just look at my portenta driver for ADS1299 , is there any other SPI library or method I should use to communicate with the ADS1299 board thats all I want to know, I am just not sure about the how to setup the SPI for Portenta, please help man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues has been resolved , use this driver for ADS1299 with Portenta h7 via SPI for any refernce while using SPI with portenta:
[My Portenta H7 Driver for ADS1299](https://github.com/ashfaquekhan/PortentaADS)